# dotnet nuget push fails when run from a Docker Build

Tags: nuget, dockerfile, dotnet-cli

I'm attempting to set up a CI pipeline for a dotnet library using docker and the dotnet cli.

I'm running a docker build statement - building this dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
COPY . ~/dotnetapp
WORKDIR ~/dotnetapp
ARG NUGET_SOURCE
ARG NUGET_API
ARG BUILD_VERSION

RUN dotnet restore ./lib1/lib1.csproj 
RUN dotnet pack ./lib1/lib1.csproj -o ./packaged -c Release /p:Version=0.0.${BUILD_VERSION}
RUN dotnet nuget push ./lib1/packaged/*.nupkg -k ${NUGET_API} -s ${NUGET_SOURCE}
```

The Restore and Pack commands execute as expected - but the push to the nuget server fails.

```
info : An error occurred while sending the request.
info :   Server returned nothing (no headers, no data) 
info :   PUT https://www.myget.org/x/xxxxxxxxx/api/v2/package/
info : An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://www.myget.org/x/xxxxxxxxx/api/v2/package/'. The request will now be re
```

tried.

I've tried multiple nuget repositories, and various flavours of the bas docker image - to no avail.

What magic incantations am I missing?